# ASP.NET WebApi - Two Controllers With Similar Action Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a scenario where I have 2 different controllers that each have multiple Get methods.  I have the methods decorated with the `ActionName` attribute, but the Routing isn't working as I think it should.

**ContactController**

```
public ContactModel GetContactByID(string id)
{
    ...
}

[ActionName("username")]
public ContactModel GetContactByUserName(string text)
{
    ...
}
```

**PaymentController**

```
public PaymentModel Get(Guid id)
{
    ...
}

[HttpGet, ActionName("sale")]
public PaymentActivityModel Sale(Guid id)
{
    ...
}
```

**Routes**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "PaymentControllerActionId", 
    "api/client/{clientId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    defaults: null 
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "ContactControllerActionText", 
    "api/client/{clientId}/{controller}/{action}/{text}", 
    defaults: null
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "ClientControllerId", 
    "api/client/{clientId}/{controller}/{id}", 
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I navigate to a Payment, it works fine.  But when I navigate to a Contact, I receive:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI, .../api/client/.../contact/username/exampleUserName
>
> No action was found on the controller 'Contact' that matches the request.

I was under the impression that the parameter name would be matched up with the action name (`text` vs. `id`).

Is the problem that one uses a `Guid` id and one uses a `string` id?

This is a client-facing API, and I have a client-friendly ContactID that is a string.  Whereas the PaymentID is a Guid.

Comment: Your Controller is a System.We.Mvc controller or a System.Web.Http.ApiController?

Answer (score 0):

First I want to point out your routes don't make a lot of sense.

This route says it is for PaymentControllerActionId, however you left the routing open to use any controller instead of specifying it is only for the Payment Controller.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "PaymentControllerActionId", 
    "api/client/{clientId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    defaults: null 
);
```

To answer your question. You likely need to specify {text} as an optional RouteParameter. Otherwise the framework usually expects that you have defined a custom routing constraint (and you should have a routing constraint on {clientId} IMO).

Also, if one of your actions expects a GUID. Put it as a Guid argument type, and WebAPI will match it correctly. Alternatively, since both functions are expecting either a name or a guid, you could just have only 1 function that takes a string, and in your db do a select statement matching the GUID or the NAME and return the contact. Much less code, easier to read, makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web API 2, then you could use attribute routing for this purpose.

In the below example, the controllers use a mix of conventional + attribute routing, but you can change this to only go by attribute routing if you need.

Example:

**Route Configuration**

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "ClientControllerId", 
    "api/client/{clientId}/{controller}/{id}", 
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

**ContactController**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/client/{clientId}/Contact")]
public class ContactController
{
    // this uses conventional route
    public ContactModel GetContactByID(string id)
    {
        ...
    }

    [Route("username/{userName}")]
    public ContactModel GetContactByUserName(string userName)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**PaymentController**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/client/{clientId}/Payment")]
public class PaymentController
{
    // this uses conventional route
    public PaymentModel Get(Guid id)
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("sale/{id}")]
    public PaymentActivityModel Sale(Guid id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```